# Dynamic SUM formula in Excel - Volume price list analysiis

Tags: excel-formula

Hello I am hoping it is possible to create a SUM field on my Product order form so that it dynamically changes what values are selected.   I have many suppliers who offer discounts on all parts based on hitting certain purchase thresholds.     For example

Product A  is $10 each,  if my total order of Product A-Z exceeds $10,000 then Product A price falls to $9, if my total order for Product A-Z exceeds $25,000 then Product A Price falls to $8  Each of these price drops are represented in a field

[Item] [Description] [Base Price] [DiscountPrice1] [DiscountPrice2] [DiscountPrice3] [Order QTY]

I assume I will need to add a field that does [Order QTY] * [Price ]  but that price will depend on the SUM of all of these fields.

I thought about doing 1 Sleeper column for each Price column so it gives me the overall SUM at the buttom for each column and then I just select the end price based on the multiple sums,  but was hoping for something cleaner.

Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, (where A1n is the first price for product A etc) if `A1n+B1n+C1n...+Z1n > 10000` then actual price is : `A2n+B2n+C2n...+Z2n` (which CAN then be <10000); How is the next step calculated? Does the customer need to reach the 25k using BASE prices, or taking into account the lower prices from the second tier already?

Comment: All calculations are based off of Base Price.  And yes once you've achieved $10,000 using Base price the order could then be less than $10,000 @user3616725

Answer (score 1):

**Read Up** on the `SUMPRODUCT()` function - [Here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) is a good explanation

Use `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate the total cost of the order using the base price, and then wrap it in two `IF`s to account for the two threshholds. IF it's below 10k, use the `SUMPRODUCT` with the base price, if it's above 10k, use the `SUMPRODUCT` referencing the second price, etc...

[image]